# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined" when button isn't undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am faced with this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined`, when the button isn't undefined. Can someone help me find the error and fix it. I am relatively new to Javascript. The HTML, Javascript and output are all included. Thanks
HTML (script linking tag isn't here):

```
<h1 id="change">Color change</h1>
<button class="color-change" data-colour="green">Green</button>
<button class="color-change" data-colour="red">Red</button>
<button class="color-change" data-colour="blue">Blue</button>
```

JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".color-change");
  var i;
  for(i=0; i<buttons.length; ++i){
    let button = buttons[i];
    console.log(button);
    document.button.onclick = function(){
      document.querySelector("#change").style.color = document.buttons[i].dataset.colour;
    }
  }
});
```

Output:

```
<button class="color-change" data-colour="green">Green</button>
index.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:24)
```

Comment: remove `document.` in `document.button`. Same in `document.buttons[i]` the next line, you don't need `document.`

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `document.` to reference the variables `button` and `buttons` you declared.

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing document won't fix this. You're using variable i in the button onclick so it will always be the last value no matter which button you click since at the time it's clicked (when the code actually runs) the loop finished.
You need to assign it to a new variable inside the loop like so

```
for(i=0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    let button = buttons[i];
    //Reaasign to new variable
    let ii = i;
    button.onclick = function(){
      document.querySelector("#change").style.color = buttons[ii].dataset.colour;
    }
 }
```